# How do I dynamically turn on/off tooltips for a WPF DataGrid in the code behind?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Is there a way to dynamically turn on/off tooltips for a WPF DataGrid in the C# code behind?

Thanks.

Comment: Where and how do you set the tooltip?

Comment: I set in the DataGrid resources XAML:             <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" >
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ToolTip >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Summary}" />
                            </ToolTip>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>

Comment: So when do you want to disable the tooltip? Under what circumstances? Please see my answer for an example of how you could enable and disable the tooltip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add/remove the `Style` programmatically:

```
Style style;
private void Button_AddOrRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGrid1.Resources.Count > 0)
    {
        style = dataGrid1.Resources[typeof(DataGridCell)] as Style;
        dataGrid1.Resources.Clear();
    }
    else if (style != null)
    {
        dataGrid1.Resources.Add(typeof(DataGridCell), style);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, Thx for the response.